# SSIS - Data source with SQL statement containing a Convert

Tags: sql, ssis

I have created an SQL OLEDB data source (SQL Server) and I have the following Command Text:

```
select replace(convert(varchar(10), dob, 111), '/', '-') As DOB FROM Person
```

I get a warning on executing that says: [OLE DB Source [1]] Warning: Truncation may occur due to retrieving data from database column "DOB" with a length of 8000 to data flow column "DOB" with a length of 10.

When I try to change the external column from 8000 to 10 (as stated in the query), the designer automatically changes it back.  I thought that external columns represented meta data in the data source.  The dob in the data source (see query above) is a varchar(10).  Why does it have to have a length of 8000? I don't have a lot of experience with SSIS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the solution.  I had to do this:

```
select cast(replace(convert(varchar(10), dob, 111), '/', '-') As varchar(10)) As DOB from Person
```

Answer (score 2):

There is another workaround to overcome this as: you can ignore the errors and execute the package from 'Truncation' erros by setting the appropriate property in 'Source' block's 'Error output' tab..

Comment: Thanks.  I am looking for a solution to this, but +1 anyway as I found this helpful.